# Same entity from different tables/procedures

Tags: nhibernate

I have 2 procedures (say A and B). They both return data with similar columns set (Id, Name, Count). To be more concrete, procedures results examples are listed below:

```
A:
Id  Name  Count
1   A     10
2   B     11

B:
Id  Name  Count
1   E     14
2   F     15
3   G     16
4   H     17
```

The IDs are generated as `ROW_NUMBER()` as I don't have own identifiers for these records because they are aggregated values.
In code I query over the both results using the same class `NameAndCountView`.
And finally my problem. When I look into results after executing both procedures sequentially I get the following:

```
A:
Id  Name  Count
1   A     10    ->|
2   B     11    ->|
                  |
B:                |
Id  Name  Count   |
1   A     10    <-|
2   B     11    <-|
3   G     16
4   H     17
```

As you can see results in the second set are replaced with results with the same IDs from the first. Of course the problem take place because I use the same class for retrieving data, right?
The question is how to make this work without creating additional `NameAndCountView2`-like class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible, and if you don't really mind about the original *Id* values, maybe you can try having the first query return even Ids :

```
ROW_NUMBER() over (order by .... )*2
```

while the second returns odd Ids :

```
ROW_NUMBER() over (order by .... )*2+1
```

This would also allow you to know where the Ids come from.

I guess this would be repeatable with N queries by having the query number *i* selecting

```
ROW_NUMBER() over (order by .... )*n+i
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Thanks for idea. I finally made it this way: `100 + ROW_NUMBER() ...`, `200 + ROW_NUMBER() ...` . As I really don't use these IDs in code and use them just for correct mappings and also I'm sure that count of rows will hardly be greated than 20 this is the solution. Thanks.